# How to save and display PDF, Excel and Word files using Laravel Framwork?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

When I save I will get this error

> Undefined variable: files

Really I don't know how to store file but I checked some blogs in google this is my store function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, $this->rules);
        if($request->hasFile('file')){
            $file = $request->file('file');
            $path = $file->getRealPath();
            $files = file_get_contents($path);
        }
        $input = $request->all();
        $charge = $request->get('charge');
        $date = $request->get('date');
        $job = $request->get('job_id');
        $id = \Auth::id();
        $current_id = DB::table('charges')->max('invoice_no');
        $data = array();
        foreach ($charge as $key=>$value ){
            $data[] = [
                'date' => $date,
                'charge'=>$value,
                'job_id'=>$job,
                'user_id'=>$id,
                'amount'=>$input['amount'][$key],
                'category'=>$input['category'][$key],
                'file'=>$files[$key], // here i will get error
                'invoice_no' => $current_id + 1,
            ];
        }
```

I'm creating our company application so we are going to host cloud. I'm confuse to store this files in my **database or disk** but everywhere we have to accesses this files. And in my show view I want display this file with the **name** and when I click that name I want display that particular document how is that possible?

EDIT 
this is my form

```
 {!! Form::model(new App\Charge, ['route' => ['charges.store'],'class'=>'form-horizontal','role'=>'form']) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('date', 'DATE :',['class'=>'col-md-2 control-label']) !!}
        <div class="col-md-7">
            {!! Form::date('date',\Carbon\Carbon::now(),null,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('job_id', 'JOB ID :',['class'=>'col-md-2 control-label']) !!}
        <div class="col-md-7">
            {!! Form::select('job_id',$job,null,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('charges', 'CHARGES :',['class'=>'col-md-2 control-label']) !!}
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="input_fields_wrap">
                <button class="add_field_button" value="">Add More Charges</button>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="charge[]">
                    <input type="text" name="category[]">
                    <input type="text" name="amount[]">
                    <input type="file" name="file[]">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-8">
            <submitfiled>
                {!! Form::submit(['class'=> 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
            </submitfiled>
        </div>
    </div>
 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Can you debug by adding `dd($files);` after line 7 and update your question?

Comment: yes same error where i use $files im getting error on that line **Undefined variable: files**

Comment: Please provide the HTML markup for the form used to initiate the request.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the `$files` variable which is only set if there is an uploaded file:

```
if($request->hasFile('file')){
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $path = $file->getRealPath();
    $files = file_get_contents($path);
}
```

So it could be possible you aren't uploading a file. Check if your form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Also make sure that you are uploading a file by checking it on line 2 with:

```
dd($request->file('file'));
```

Let's say the file upload worked, you read the entire file into a `string` with `file_get_contents()` and assign it to `$files`

But later in the code you assume `$files` is an `array`:

```
'file'=>$files[$key], // here i will get error
```

Try to debug your your variables to see what actually is in them.

Also I would copy the file to an upload directory and only save the path to this file instead of the whole file as a string.

Comment: i just tried `dd($request->file('file'));` its null out put why is that ?

Comment: Because there is is no file uploaded. Does your `<form>` have the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` tag? Does the file input in your form have the name `file`?

Comment: i add encrypt in my form i checked dd() now im getting out put of that file deatils but getRealPath();,getClientOriginalName() cant acces why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are having problems with uploading but you already got there, right?

After storing it, you would have a route with parameter that streams or downloads the related file.

Check also

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

https://github.com/PHPOffice

You will find great way